# Leaner Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Linux distributions range from very lean (Arch) to heavy (Ubuntu).  Is there a version of Windows-10 or a process that can reshape Windows so that one is running the "Arch" (minimal) version of Windows?  I would be grateful if a Google search keyword would return the subject matter.  Thank you

This question is concerned with computer software (Windows) It is my understanding that [superuser on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) subject matter comprise:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
> question about …
>
> ```
> computer hardware,
> computer software, or
> personal and home computer networking
> ```

and it [said question] is not about …

```
programming and software development,
video games or consoles,
websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,
```

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: If you are going to buy a few thousands copies their is Windows Embedded where you choose what components to buy.

Comment: Windows simply isn't the right choice for this purpose. you'll never accomplish what you want, and the closer you get destroys the very characteristics that might make windows a decent choice.

Comment: You'll want to check out the [MSFN Forum](https://msfn.org/board/), which has numerous threads about this. While I don't believe this is the reason for your question, Windows Setup will adjust what it installs, and what services it configures, depending on the hardware specs of the machine it's being installed on.

Answer (score 1):

I use Powershell to uninstall a lot of the pre-installed programs which are mainly Windows Store Apps. There are simple Powershell commands available to do this.
This seems to lighten up the install for me.